# SQL Server 2008 T-SQL UDF Split() Tailoring

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I'm useing SQL Ser 2008 and have a large table with only one column of data. The data is a random string with very little consistency. Eample: Name Account 445566 0010020056893010445478008 AFD 369. I've been working with a split function that a stackoverflow user suggested. It works great but the function assigns the split string into one column. I need a row of individual columns. The present result is 1col with values Name, Account, 445566,...  in it but the result I'm looking for is col1 Name, col2 Account, col3 445566,...
If anyone could provide some insight on how to tailor this script or its usage to get the desired result it would be much appreciated.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] 
(    
 @String varchar(max) 
,@Delimiter char 
) 
RETURNS @Results table 
( 
 Ordinal int 
,StringValue varchar(max) 
) 
as 
begin 

set @String = isnull(@String,'') 
set @Delimiter = isnull(@Delimiter,'') 

declare 
 @TempString varchar(max) = @String 
,@Ordinal int = 0 
,@CharIndex int = 0 

set @CharIndex = charindex(@Delimiter, @TempString) 
while @CharIndex != 0 begin      
    set @Ordinal += 1        
    insert @Results values 
    ( 
     @Ordinal 
    ,substring(@TempString, 0, @CharIndex) 
    )        
    set @TempString = substring(@TempString, @CharIndex + 1, len(@TempString) - @CharIndex)      
    set @CharIndex = charindex(@Delimiter, @TempString) 
end 

if @TempString != '' begin 
    set @Ordinal += 1  
    insert @Results values 
    ( 
     @Ordinal 
    ,@TempString 
    ) 
end 

return 
end 

--The usage:
SELECT    
* 
FROM    
mytable M    
CROSS APPLY    
[dbo].[Split] (M.TheColumn, ' ') S
Where rtrim(s.StringValue) != ''
```

Comment: Incidently, The function is borrowed from @antisanity and its usage over the table came from @gbn. Thanks Guys!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is this data being maintained or is it an import? Will the output table's width vary or will it be static?

Comment: I'm reverse engineering an old flat file batch. The data consists of strings containing 120 characters. The table width will be a static number of columns. My goal is to break the string up into a row of columns not just one column containing all the data but 9 or 10 columns. This will affect something like 10000 rows of data at a time. Thanks again antisanity for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you have 6 columns in the string you can use a split functions that looks like this and of course modify the function to whatever number of columns you want. A function can not return a dynamic number of columns.

```
create function dbo.Split6(@String varchar(max), @Delimiter char(1)) 
returns table as return
(
  select
    substring(T.Col, 1, S1.Pos-1) as Col1,
    substring(T.Col, S1.Pos+1, S2.Pos-S1.Pos-1) as Col2,
    substring(T.Col, S2.Pos+1, S3.Pos-S2.Pos-1) as Col3,
    substring(T.Col, S3.Pos+1, S4.Pos-S3.Pos-1) as Col4,
    substring(T.Col, S4.Pos+1, S5.Pos-S4.Pos-1) as Col5,
    substring(T.Col, S5.Pos+1, S6.Pos-S5.Pos-1) as Col6
  from (select @String+replicate(@Delimiter, 6)) as T(Col)
    cross apply (select charindex(@Delimiter, T.Col, 1)) as S1(Pos)
    cross apply (select charindex(@Delimiter, T.Col, S1.Pos+1)) as S2(Pos)
    cross apply (select charindex(@Delimiter, T.Col, S2.Pos+1)) as S3(Pos)
    cross apply (select charindex(@Delimiter, T.Col, S3.Pos+1)) as S4(Pos)
    cross apply (select charindex(@Delimiter, T.Col, S4.Pos+1)) as S5(Pos)
    cross apply (select charindex(@Delimiter, T.Col, S5.Pos+1)) as S6(Pos)
)
```

Test:

```
declare @T table (Col varchar(100))

insert into @T values
 ('Name Account 445566 0010020056893010445478008 AFD 369'),
 (''),
 ('1 2'),
 ('1  3')

select S.Col1, S.Col2, S.Col3, S.Col4, S.Col5, S.Col6
from @T as T
  cross apply
    dbo.Split6(T.Col, ' ') as S
```

Result:

```
Col1  Col2     Col3    Col4                       Col5  Col6
----  -------  ------  -------------------------  ----  ----
Name  Account  445566  0010020056893010445478008  AFD   369

1     2             
1              3
```

Comment: This looks good. I will eventually find out exactly how many columns I need so I think this will work nicely! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a PIVOT.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: I should be able to PIVOT the table column after the script is used but I was looking for a way around that. My thoughts were if you can split a string and insert the data to one column maybe you could assign it to several different columns within the script.

Comment: I know this sounds like I'm not useing the most obvious tool but I'm half conserned with performance ( pivoting a table with over 100000 rows hopefully not hitting the cpu twice is still going to take a while coupled with the process happening several times over) and half just trying to see if this could be done. I'm not well versed in T-Sql so I thought I'd ask the experts.